# asp.net configuration error

Tags: asp.net

### Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 35:                
Line 36:                
Line 37:                
Line 38:                
Line 39:

Source File: F:\aspnet\WebSite1\web.config    Line: 37

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = suren-PC\suren
LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///F:/aspnet/WebSite1/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = F:\aspnet\WebSite1\bin

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: F:\aspnet\WebSite1\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/suren/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/website1/e666b402/d061aee1/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/suren/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/website1/e666b402/d061aee1/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/aspnet/WebSite1/bin/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/aspnet/WebSite1/bin/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/suren/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/website1/e666b402/d061aee1/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/suren/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/website1/e666b402/d061aee1/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/aspnet/WebSite1/bin/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/aspnet/WebSite1/bin/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.EXE.

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong reference. The correct version of the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly is `3.5.0.0`:

```
System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

As the error suggests check out line 37 of `F:\aspnet\WebSite1\web.config` and see if you can put the correct version number.

Answer (score 0):

In the project, expand your References, and if System.Data.DataSetExtensions is listed, remove it.  Then add a reference to the library.  That will (should) update your web.config with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually remove the reference and then ad the correct reference by selecting Add Reference and select the correct version. Check your config file to see if the correct version number is displayed, if not, add it (3.5.0.0).